# Understanding sqlite3_step and why it "takes time" between iterations

Tags: c, sqlite

I'm wondering why sometimes the query results return quite quick and other times it seems to take a while between the `sqlite3_step()` calls. For example:

```
rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "SELECT * FROM mytable m GROUP BY field1, field2, field3, field4, field5 LIMIT 500", -1, &stmt, NULL);
while ((rc = sqlite3_step(stmt)) == SQLITE_ROW);
```

Each `sqlite3_step` takes about the same time when I view the print  statements, and the fetch statements add up to take about `6.5s`

And then with a normal, fast unaggregated query, `sqlite3_step` is almost instant:

```
rc = sqlite3_prepare(db, "SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT 500", -1, &stmt, NULL);
```

In the above query, everything takes under `0.1s` to query and retrieve.

I understand why the query itself would be much slower, but it seems like `sqlite3_stmt` is not really "doing anything" and all the SQL-ing work goes into the `sqlite3_step` and is spread out within each step. A few questions from this:

- Why aren't the resultset fetched once, and successive steps returned instantly (for a small queryset, such as the above where there are  less than 1K records)?
- What exactly is `sqlite3_prepare` doing? Does it touch the actual file (or in-memory) data, or is merely just "setting up" for the query to run?
- What is SQLite doing between each `sqlite3_step` that it is taking additional time between steps (if the query has already been 'executed')?

The documentation of this method is listed [here](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/step.html), but it doesn't say much about what it actually does other than saying what return codes it might give. From the docs:

> This routine is used to evaluate a prepared statement that has been previously created by the sqlite3_prepare() interface. The statement is evaluated up to the point where the first row of results are available. To advance to the second row of results, invoke sqlite3_step() again. Continue invoking sqlite3_step() until the statement is complete. Statements that do not return results (ex: INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statements) run to completion on a single call to sqlite3_step().

What does "to completion" mean in this case? Does it basically just do a `LIMIT 1` and the user needs to call it again to do an `OFFSET 1`, or what does that mean exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sqlite3_prepare()` compiles the statement into sqlite's [internal bytecode](https://www.sqlite.org/opcode.html). `sqlite3_step()` evaluates that bytecode up to the point where a row is returned or there are no more rows. The next call resumes evaluating at that point; it doesn't always calculate all result rows all at once, but often just one at a time. `sqlite3_step()` can take different times depending on how much work has to be done to get the next row (like processing groups of different sizes), if pages have to be fetched from disc instead of being present in the page cache, etc.